# Snapping vector to a point from a grid on a sphere (icosahedron)

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, vector, 3d

here is a problem that will turn your brain inside out, I'm trying to deal with it for a quite some time already.

Suppose you have sphere located in the origin of a 3d space. The sphere is segmented into a grid of equidistant points. The procedure that forms grid isn't that important but what seems simple to me is to use regular 3d computer graphics sphere generation procedure (The algorithm that forms the sphere described in the picture below)

Now, after I have such sphere (i.e. icosahedron of some degree) I need a computationally trivial procedure that will be capable to snap (an angle) of a random unit vector to it's closest icosahedron edge points. Also it is acceptable if the vector will be snapped to a center point of triangle that the vector is intersecting.

I would like to emphasise that it is important that the procedure should be computationally trivial. This means that procedures that actually create a sphere in memory and then involve a search among every triangle in sphere is not a good idea because such search will require access to global heap and ram which is slow because I need to perform this procedure millions of times on a low end mobile hardware.

The procedure should yield it's result through a set of mathematical equations based only on two values, the vector and degree of icosahedron (i.e. sphere)

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

============

**Edit**

One afterthought that just came to my mind, it seems that within diagram below step 3 (i.e. Project each new vertex to the unit sphere) is not important at all, because after bisection, projection of every vertex to a sphere would preserve all angular characteristics of a bisected shape that we are trying to snap to. So the task simplifies to identifying a bisected sub triangle coordinates that are penetrated by vector.

[image: This is icosahedron]

Comment: Re, the last note: I think that you would still need to project each vertex if you're doing more than 1 iteration of the algorithm, wouldn't you? Otherwise, it seems like the successive splits on a non-projected isocahedron would introduce small, but noticeable errors.

Comment: On a separate note: Do you have an actual sphere model to work with, or is this problem working entirely through data?

Comment: If your points are created by successive bisection (quadsection?) you could follow the resulting structure to find which triangle the point lies in. Try every face of the original icosahedron to see which face the point lies in. Now that face was divided into four. Look to see which of those four sub-triangles the point lies in. That triangle was in turn divided into four. Look to see which of the four sub-triangles the point lies in, and so on, until you get an answer for the smallest sub-division.

Comment: "icosahedron of some degree" - not sure what this means, and the diagrams you've included suggest that your polyhedron isn't actually an icosahedron. Do you mean an icosahedron (there's only one polyhedron called an icosahedron), or one of these other things?

Comment: AFAIK, It's not equidistant because there's a different ratio from a point in the center of the triangle and a point in the middle of an edge. the number of points is given by 2 + 10·4N... I'd not overthink it because it's an irregular task with exceptions and so forth, i'd use 3D models. else treat the sphere as only one 12th of itself as a side of the ICOS, figure out the triangles on it and then rotate it 12 times.

Answer (score 3):

Make a table with 20 entries of top-level icosahedron faces coordinates - for example, build them from [wiki coordinate set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron#Cartesian_coordinates))

> The vertices of an icosahedron centered at the origin with an
>   edge-length of 2 and a circumscribed sphere radius of 2 sin (2π/5) are
>   described by circular permutations of:

```
 V[] = (0, ±1, ±ϕ)
 where ϕ = (1 + √5)/2
 is the golden ratio (also written τ).
```

and calculate corresponding central vectors C[] (sum of three vectors for vertices of  every face).

Find the closest central vector using maximum of dot product (DP) of your vector P and all C[]. Perhaps, it is possible to reduce number of checks accounting for P components (for example if dot product of P and some V[i] is negative, there is no sense to consider faces being neighbors of V[i]). Don't sure  that this elimination takes less time than direct full comparison of DP's with centers.

When big triangle face is determined, [project P onto the plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444968/project-a-point-in-3d-on-a-given-plane) of that face and get coordinates of P' in u-v (decompose AP' by AB and AC, where A,B,C are face vertices).

Multiply u,v by 2^N (degree of subdivision).

```
 u' = u * 2^N
 v' = v * 2^N
 iu = Floor(u')
 iv = Floor(v')
 fu = Frac(u')
 fv = Frac(v')
```

Integer part of u' is "row" of small triangle, integer part of v' is "column". Fractional parts are trilinear coordinates inside small triangle face, so we can choose the smallest value of `fu, fv, 1-fu-fv` to get the closest vertice. Calculate this closest vertex and normalize vector if needed.

Comment: Trying to check this solution

Comment: I have doubts about correctness of 'plain' subdivision of triangle face. It definitely works for the first subdivision level, but not sure about next levels.

Answer (score 1):

It's not equidistant, you can see if you study [this](https://scienceisbeauty.tumblr.com/post/3964427789/icosahedron-which-has-20-triangles-12-vertices) version: 
[image]

It's a problem of [geodesic dome frequency](https://simplydifferently.org/Geodesic_Dome_Notes?page=1) and some people have spent time researching all known methods to do that geometry: http://geo-dome.co.uk/article.asp?uname=domefreq, see that guy is a self labelled geodesizer :)

One page told me that the progression goes like this:  2 + 10·4N (12,42,162...)

You can simplify it down to a simple flat fractal triangle, where every triangle devides into 4 smaller triangles, and every time the subdivision is rotated 12 times around a sphere.

Logically, it is only one triangle rotated 12 times, and if you solve the code on that side, then you have the lowest computation version of the geodesic spheres.

If you don't want to keep the 12 sides as a series of arrays, and you want a lower memory version, then you can read about midpoint subdivision code, there's a lot of versions of midpoint subdivision.

I may have completely missed something. just that there isn't a true equidistant geodesic dome, because a triangle doesn't map to a sphere, only for icos.

Comment: Hi @com.prehensible you were referring to "it" when saying stating that "It's not equidistant" sorry for excessive intrusiveness, but I really didn't caught what specific characteristic was not equidistant. The center-point of a triangle looks pretty equidistant to me, or I might be missing something. In any case what's more important is a practical aspect of this task, I need an algorithm, that will be able to map an arbitrary real-valued unit vector into it's triangle normal which it penetrates, or it may be edge points.

Comment: Hi, the vertices of the 12 sided Icosahedron become the centers of 5 triangles later in the division, whereas the new vertices from midpoints are all at the center of 6 triangles. that's why I don't think it's equidistant. If we know why you need that algorythm and what the programming task is, it would be easier to understand the method for solving it.

Comment: I'm performing 3d reconstruction of space, when measuring surface in some specific point of space instead of just one point I get a burst of points that lay on a ray (due to inaccuracy of measuring procedures). I need to filter out those points down to one which gets most hits when being observed from different angles. So I need an index for rays. One way to do that is to use quad / octree but it's terribly inefficient. So instead I need a way to round a vector to it's nearest neighbour on a grid of a sphere, this would give good way to index rays and get them in O(1) from dictionary.

Comment: But the distribution of vector directions should be rather more than less uniform i.e. equidistant if looking from another perspective